# L'aggettivo "sedicente" ha sempre una connotazione negativa?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Leggendo le notizie in italiano ho trovato spesso l'espressione

> il sedicente Stato Islamico.

Penso che il significato di "sedicente" in questa espressione corrisponda a questa definizione del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sedicente/):

> Che dice di essere, che si spaccia per qualcuno, che si attribuisce cioè titoli, generalità, qualifiche, qualità che non sono o che si sospettano non essere rispondenti a quelle reali: *il s. dottore è stato smascherato; hanno accertato le vere generalità del s. console; un s. ispettore ha truffato varî commercianti*

Il senso sarebbe che l'ISIS si è autoproclamato come stato, ma non è riconosciuto come tale dagli altri stati. È ovvio che questo significato spiegato dal Treccani ha una connotazione negativa. Tuttavia, alla stessa voce "sedicente" del Treccani appare un'altra accezione che sembra essere più neutra:

> anche in senso più obiettivo, che si afferma tale: *l’attentato è stato rivendicato da un s. gruppo di separatisti baschi*.

Comunque, anche questo ultimo esempio del Treccani (si parla di un gruppo di separatisti che commette attentati terroristici), ha secondo me una connotazione negativa. Quindi, la domanda sarebbe: è possibile usare l'aggettivo "sedicente" senza dare alla frase una sfumatura negativa? Per esempio, potrei dire "la sedicente *cantantessa*" in riferimento a [Carmen Consoli](http://palermo.repubblica.it/cronaca/2015/03/09/news/carmen_consoli_ritorno_in_sicilia_e_tempo_di_dire_grazie_alla_mia_terra_-109127700/) (nel senso che Carmen Consoli si fa chiamare in questo insolito modo)?

Comment: Il problema non è tanto la connotazione negativa, quanto il credere o meno che un “sedicente X” sia veramente un X. Nel caso del sedicente ispettore, crediamo o sappiamo che in realtà non lo era. I separatisti baschi invece – posto che non è una bella cosa commettere attentati – fino a prova contraria lo sono davvero: è solo che non ne abbiamo un conferma indipendente. Il succo è che “sedicente” si può usare in entrambi i casi, anche se forse prevale il primo.

Comment: @DaG: Capisco che questa è la differenza tra le due accezioni riportate dal Treccani. Quello che ha motivato la mia domanda però è il fatto che l'esempio del secondo significato faccia riferimento a un gruppo terroristico, cioè a qualcosa che di solito viene considerato come negativo per la società.

Comment: Sì, ma non direi che “sedicenti” si usi solo in contesti negativi: vedi la risposta di Maria Sanchez. Inoltre potrei dire, per esempio, che “StackExchange ha ricevuto una donazione di 10.000 dollari da un sedicente benefattore del genere umano”, come a dire che non sono io a definirlo così, ma è come lui descrive sé stesso. In effetti, forse fra le righe si potrebbe avvertire un certo scetticismo da parte mia sulle reali intenzioni del donatore.

Comment: @DaG Il caso dei terroristi mi ricorda molto le “sedicenti Brigate Rosse”, che adombrava il dubbio che fossero veramente “rossi”.

Answer (score 1):

Non credo che si possa utilizzare in un contesto positivo.

```
Coniugato, Medico. Sedicente poiché i documenti oggetto di furto.
```

Questo sarebbe un frammento di una denuncia reale, la quale è presentata da un uomo perché gli hanno rubato il suo portafoglio. Dato che quest'uomo non ha i documenti per verificare la sua identità, è **sedicente**, giacché potrebbe essere falso quello che ha detto.

Spero che questa informazione sia utile.

Answer (score 0):

In generale non è possibile usare "sedicente" in maniera positiva proprio perché stiamo implicando che il soggetto che si definisce in un certo modo stia dicendo il falso o stia affermando qualcosa senza avere l'autorità per farlo.

Nell'esempio riportato da Charo non sono sicuro che si possa dire "sedicente" in quanto sembra che il termine "cantantessa" sia stato coniato da altri e non sia una definizione creata, ma solo accettata, dalla Consoli. Ad ogni modo, anche "la sedicente cantantessa" mi pare avere una connotazione negativa. Come se la Consoli dicesse: "so che non si può dire in italiano, ma la accetto lo stesso perchè...voglio passare come una che canta".

Comment: “Cantantessa” non era detto per errore: Carmen Consoli trova divertente definirsi così (http://palermo.repubblica.it/cronaca/2015/03/09/news/carmen_consoli_ritorno_in_sicilia_e_tempo_di_dire_grazie_alla_mia_terra_-109127700/?ref=twhl&utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter). Forse la tua risposta va cambiata alla luce di questo fatto: il “sedicente” di Charo si riferiva proprio a questa insolita denominazione, presumo.

Comment: Come ha detto @DaG, intendevo esprimere che Carmen Consoli fa chiamare "cantantessa" a sé stessa.

Comment: chiedo scusa: non avevo proprio notato il link all'articolo quindi avevo inteso male tutto il senso del tuo esempio

Answer (score 0):

Direi che ho sempre sentito l'utilizzo dell'aggettivo ***sedicente*** sempre con una connotazione negativa.

A riprova questo basta considerare alcuni dei suoi sinonimi: ***abusivo***, ***falso***, ***finto***, ***millantatore***, ***preteso***.

Per quanto riguarda la frase su Carmen Consoli, così come la scrivi avrebbe una connotazione negativa, anche se potrebbe essere intesa come

> Carmen Consoli, che si autodefinisce cantantessa...

cioè lei usa un termine forzato, non comune per definire sé stessa che qui assume un carattere non negativo perché è una cantante molto brava e apprezzata.

Capita di leggere sui giornali:

> Il sedicente mago richiedeva denaro ai suoi clienti per improbabili riti magici

Un personaggio sedicente è uno che dice di essere qualcuno o qualcosa ma non è niente, come un sedicente mago dice di essere un mago ma in realtà non lo è, oppure un sedicente dottore dice di essere tale ma non ha la laurea.